# How to create non filtered summary in a filtered report in crystal reports

Tags: filter, crystal-reports

Pretty new to CR

I have a grouped survey report filtered by a parameter so (of course) all the summary's in the report are being filtered by the parameter.

I need a "average" summary on a group (question) that is not filtered by the parameter.

Not sure on how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to tackle this problem, but the one that will require the fewest changes to your report will be if you use a SQL Expression (basically a subquery) to get that unfiltered average.

Let's say that you're grouping your report by `{table.group}` and looking for the average of `{table.number}`. You could create an expression like:

```
case when "table"."group" is null then null
else (select average(number)
      from table
      where group="table"."group")
end
```

Note that the double-quoted fields refer back to the main query, so you're effectively correlating the average per group back to each row from the main report which can then be used in the Group Footer or Group Header.

Comment: Hello Ryan, I am tring your approch (1st time with sql)I have `case when "'360_'"."Theme" is null then null
else (select average(Score)
      from table
      where group="'360_'"."Theme")
end` I get "syntax error" where `'360_'`.`Theme` is the grouping and `'360_'`.`Score` is what I want the average of.  Thanks

Comment: First of all, what are you using for a data source? I'd suggest instead of typing out the fields from your main report manually, like `"360_"."Theme"`, just double click on the field from the SQL Expression Editor (the window you're in when creating the SQL Expression) and Crystal will insert it with correct syntax automatically.

Comment: I am using excel, and I did "double click on the field from the SQL Expression Editor".